# The LINQ expression could not be translated for simple computed property

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

We are using `.NET Core 3.1`, [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/3.1.9) and [Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 3.1.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/3.1.4). We have the following database model:

`Template.cs`

```cs
[Table("template", Schema = "test")]
public partial class Template
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [Column("name")]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [Column("owner_id")]
    public int? OwnerId { get; set; }
}
```

`Template.partial.cs`

```cs
public partial class Template
{
    public bool IsPublic => OwnerId == null;
}
```

We have the following function which queries the database for records where `OwnerId == null` (it uses computed property `IsPublic` defined in partial class):

```cs
public List<Template> GetAllPublicTemplates()
{
    return _testDbContext.Template
        .Where(x => x.IsPublic)
        .ToList();
}
```

When `GetAllPublicTemplates` is called, the following exception is thrown:

```
'The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Template>
    .Where(t => t.IsPublic)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'
```

I understand what the exception means, but I am wondering why it occurs. If I use `.Where(x => x.OwnerId == null)` (the same predicate as `IsPublic`) it works as expected. Why can't EF Core translate simple calculated property defined in partial class? Is this by-design or am I doing something wrong? Where is this behavior documented?

Comment: `IsPublic` is not mapped to column, that's why you have this exception. EF Core cannot look into method body (property getter) and understand that you want to replace `IsPublic` with `OwnerId == null`. Anyway it is possible to define such properties, which can be used in queries, but only with help form third party extensions, like LINQKit.

Comment: It can't translate it because LINQ works by translating expression trees, not arbitrary code. The property access is a call to an arbitrary method that could contain any code, and at runtime the query provider cannot "see through it". Putting `x => x.OwnerId == null` in a query is therefore fundamentally different from `x => x.IsPublic`. A solid workaround would be to define `OwnerId` as a computed column in the database itself, if you're allowed to make schema changes, as this makes the logic available to anything accessing the database, not just your code.